# How to invoke method in Activity from another Activity without startActivityForResult()?

Tags: android

I have two activities. Activity1 contains TextView with HTML links. When user click any link - it launch Activity2 (so I cannot use startActivityForResult()). Then user make some actions in Activity2, click "Back" button and return to Activity1. At this moment I need to invoke method in Activity1 with information from Activity2. But how to do that? I need to use BroadcastReceiver?

For launching Activity2 I using this:

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And all links in my TextView start with "myapp://".

Comment: Why can't you use `startActivityForResult(...)`?

Comment: Why can't you use startActivityForResult?  How are you launching Activity2?

Comment: you can utilize the use of SharedPreferences for moving data from one activity to other

Comment: I update my question and add code, which explain it. I start Activity2 on user click on link with my own scheme.

Comment: What "information" do you need to return?  The questions are relevant because calling an application method from another application is not the way to go.

Comment: @Simon, I need to return one integer value.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя, Is it proper way? Is it better BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @BArtWell yes this is also one of way by which we can share data between Application components

Comment: Thank's a lot :) It is working fine with SharedPreferences.